# Calling django model functions inside templates

Tags: django

I have the following function inside a model:

```
@property
def exclusive_price(self):
    if(self.discount_price > 0):
        return self.list_price - self.discount_price
    else:
        return self.list_price
```

I tried calling it inside a template, but nothing is being outputted. What can I do?

```
{{obj.exlusive_price}}
```

Comment: The above should work, need more context.

Comment: Kindly verify obj. If you still having issues then please describe what error you comes up with.

Comment: The above as far as syntax goes works as expected. There is something fishy happening that we can't see for your example. Could you post more code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not working because you are calling exlusive_price not exclusive_price. c is missing.

Comment: but the logic was true. There was some spell mistake. Thanks for the argue.

Comment: your logic is true. I didn't meant your wrong. I just expected someone (one person) will be down voted you.

Comment: As expected some one (one person) up Voted.

Comment: that's nice I will also up vote you :) and I think he reverse his down vote to up vote

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's not a cut-and-paste error, your method is called `exclusive_price` but you're calling `exlusive_price`, without the `c`.